# Conversion To JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jakarta-ee, jstl

I'm a newbie to advanced jsp so I wrote my initial code in jsp scripts. My jsp pages are currently using jsp scripts to evaluate conditions, Since there are some problems like re-usability, readability etc. Hence I have been changing my code to remove all jsp scripts and use JSTL instead, I have encountered a problem when came to a condition that came inside an HTML tag. A sample line of code that I want to convert is given below.

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse <% if ("m".equals(request.getParameter("type"))) { %> in <%}%>">
```

In the above code the class "in" is what highlights this div, I want this class to come only if there is a certain value in the request. Can we do this operation in JSTL.

Comment: Have a try with the ternary operator: `${type eq 'm' ? 'in' : ''}`.

Comment: ${type} will be a page, request, session, or application-scoped attribute.  Try `${param.type eq 'm' ? 'in' : ''}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following in your code as advised by Tap

```
<div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse ${param.type eq 'm' ? 'in' : ''}">
```